# Парсинг авито. Доступ ограничен: проблема с IP

Tags: python, requests, beautiful-soup, proxy, ip

Стоит задача парсинга авито, но никак не получается. Использую платный прокси, ввожу заголовки:

```
User_Agent
Accept
Accept-Encoding
Accept-Language
Cookie
```

но все равно ничего не срабатывает, продолжает выдавать

```
Доступ ограничен: проблема с IP
```

Может кто-то имел дело с авито и сможет подсказать? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Так мы вряд ли сможем вам помочь, предоставьте код, или минимально воспроизводимый пример, информации явно не достаточно.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be&searchOn=3

Comment: Думаете этот платный прокси там не забанен давно? Ну-ну ))